# Specify an optional reference in your Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

I have a Sponsors model and a Promo Codes model.

- A sponsor can have **zero or more** promo codes
- A promo code can have **zero or one** sponsors

Thus a promo code should have an optional reference to a sponsor, that is, a `sponsor_id` that may or may not have a value. I'm not sure how to set this up in Rails.

Here's what I have so far:

```
# app/models/sponsor.rb
class Sponsor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :promo_codes  # Zero or more.
end
```

---

```
# app/models/promo_code.rb
class PromoCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :sponsor  # Zero or one.
end
```

---

```
# db/migrate/xxxxx_add_sponsor_reference_to_promo_codes.rb
# rails g migration AddSponsorReferenceToPromoCodes sponsor:references
# Running migration adds a sponsor_id field to promo_codes table.
class AddSponsorReferenceToPromoCodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :promo_codes, :sponsor, index: true
  end
end
```

Does this make sense? I'm under the impression that I have to use `belongs_to` in my Promo Codes model, but I have no basis for this, just that I've haven't seen a `has_many` with `has_one` example yet.

Comment: What made this more confusing for me was the title of this Rails Guides association section: "[Choosing Between belongs_to and has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one)". I interpreted it as choosing `has_one` _or_ `belongs_to`. The section is actually about using both; which goes in which model.

Comment: I also learned that `belongs_to` is always on the model with the foreign key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a simple has_many and belongs_to relationship:

```
# app/models/sponsor.rb
class Sponsor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :promo_codes  # Zero or more.
end

# app/models/promo_code.rb
#table has sponsor_id field
class PromoCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sponsor  # Zero or one.
end
```

has_one isn't appropriate here, as it would replace has_many:  ie, you either have "has_many" and "belongs_to" OR "has_one" and "belongs_to".  has_one isn't generally used much:  usually it is used when you already have a has_many relationship that you want to change to has_one, and don't want to restructure the existing tables.

Comment: This answer was correct when it was written, but not anymore (but is still accepted and this might cause confusion). Not to steal correct answer, if you are reading this and using Rails 5+, check also answer by Paul Ardeleanu bellow

Answer (score 88):

In Rails 5, belongs_to is defined as required by default. To make it optional use the 'optional' option :)

```
class User
  belongs_to :company, optional: true
end
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18233

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: For good clarification, read this article. Very well-written: simple and understandable.
https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify validation, relationships are optional by default.

The `belongs_to` is to tell rails the other half of the relationship between those two objects so you can also call `@promo_code.sponsor` and, vice versa, `@sponsor.promo_codes`.

Comment: So to be clear, the `has_many` in the Sponsors model allows you to do `@sponsor.promo_codes`, and the `belongs_to` in the Promo Codes model allows you to do `@promo_code.sponsor`?

Comment: Not correct anymore. Rails 5 keeps default to `required: true`, we need to pass `optional: true` to make it optional